# JS task doesn't run in IE until the mouse moves over a new element

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I have this code, that is supposed to run at the completion of an event, but the code is not executed until the mouse moves around on the screen a little bit (usually need to mouseover a different element.

Here is the code I have:

```
 //Animation is finished here
 //On Animation Completion do this code
 $('.footer-nav-links a').removeClass('active');
 var newplus = vars.current_slide + 1;
 $('.footer-nav-links a:nth-child(' + newplus +')').addClass('active');
```

If I throw an alert in front of the first line, the alert executes every time and then the rest of the code works fine after I close the alert, but for some reason this chunk of code doesn't work in IE by itself, until I hover over some other element. Is there a known problem with IE, a problem with this code, or could I have other issues that I should be on the lookout for? Thanks!

Comment: Might not really help, but you'd better use this : `$('.footer-nav-links a').eq(newplus)`

Comment: could you describe the logic of your website in detail or make a jsfiddle with your scripts ?